# Simplest way to handle two if conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is the same as a previous question but I made many mistakes while describing the question there. So I'm trying again. Please excuse my terminology. It might be wrong. I am new to programming.

I have two pointers to objects (I think) A and B . They look somewhat like this:

```
Class1* A = Blah->Method1();
Class2* B = A->Method2();
```

I have to check the existence of these before executing some code. Here are the conditions:

- A and B both exist : Perform Action1 and Action2
- One of them exists, one of them is null: Perform only Action1
- Both are null: Perform only Action1

Here is the code I have so far:

```
if (A){
/*some code here. B is created here */
    if (B){
        // Perform action1. Action1 always comes before Action2
        // Perform action2
    }
}
else{
    //Perform action1
}
```

This works for 3 out of the 4 cases. It fails when A exists but B is null.

How can I improve this? 
(if possible, while keeping `//Perform Action 1` inside the innermost if. Other suggestions are also welcome.)

Thank you.

Comment: Remove Action1 from the problem, since it's unconditional?

Comment: What you really should look at is that `Action1` isn't really conditional. It always gets performed.

Comment: Re-asking the same question on SO is rarely a good idea. Have a look at the [**help center**](http://stackoverflow.com/help), how to handle this properly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm assuming user3207920 re-asked because of Ben Voigt's suggestion that they do so.

Comment: @KyleStrand But one or the other question should be deleted then ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed. I'm just pointing out that user3207920 is getting some conflicting advice, which isn't their fault.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   
 I asked what the protocol was in the previous question's comments. I was told to create a new question.  I tried deleting that question but I got an error msg saying 'This question has answers. It cannot be deleted.' I didn't know what to do.

Comment: @user3207920: If you want the old one deleted (and you should, the answers are a complete mess from trying to keep up with a question that changed 5 times or more?), just edit the whole question into a link to the new question and "Please delete this old version".  Even though you can't delete it, we can (if enough people agree).

Comment: @user3207920 You can edit one question (the one with the most appropriate answers for you), and flag the other one asking the admins to delete it. Additionally you might flag the remaining one for reopening, if it was closed or is on hold.

Answer (score 6):

> - A and B both exist : Perform Action1 and Action2
> - One of them exists, one of them is null: Perform only Action1
> - Both are null: Perform only Action1

So, really, you want:

```
action1();

if (a && b) {
  action2();
}
```

Your criteria *always* involve invoking `action1`; there is no reason for it to be guarded by an `if`. You then invoke `action2` if both `a` and `b` are found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick clarification. Was it correct of me to call A and B as pointers to objects?

Comment: Also, @user3207920, if you need `B` to be conditionally created based on whether `A` exists, just add an additional `if (A)` block before `action1()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is *much* clearer than last time.  And that makes the solution straightforward:

```
bool doAction2 = false;
if (A) {
    /*some code here. B is created here */
    doAction2 = (B != null);
}
action1();
if (doAction2) {
    action2();
}
```